# Browser based Javascript/CSS editor with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, editor

Is anyone aware of a browser based editor that has autocomplete for Javascript and CSS? I know of typescript (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/), but want something a little more complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Check out CodeMirror

> **CodeMirror** is a JavaScript component that provides a code editor in the browser. When a mode is available for the language you are coding in, it will color your code, and optionally help with indentation.
>
> A rich programming API and a CSS theming system are available for customizing CodeMirror to fit your application, and extending it with new functionality.

#### More info: http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 3):

Cloud9 IDE is pretty nifty as well. https://c9.io/